# How do you configure specific cipher suites for Java

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I'm a novice when it comes to Java.  I'm trying to eliminate weak ciphers from my systems.  Using wireshark I have a connection to another server and it shows 45 ciphers available.  I discovered that the connection made is done with java (by using netstat) and I found running the command:

```
jrunscript -e "java.util.Arrays.asList(javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().getSupportedCipherSuites()).stream().forEach(println)"
```

displays 45 ciphers.  So I suspect it's Java that is determining the ciphers.

Is there a way to configure java to only use what ciphers I want, and if I ran the above command again, would it only display those ciphers?

I've already tried modifying the java.security file by adding the following line:

```
jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  Google doesn't seem to turn up much else, so I come here as a last resort.  I'm unable to copy/paste any config files as my systems are on another network.

Comment: Your first command is using [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html). You can add a _filter_ before the _forEach_.

Comment: `jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites` is a _system_ property, not a security property; to set it you must [use `-D` on the command line or equivalent in an IDE etc, or call `System.setProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#how-to-specify-a-java-lang-system-property)

Comment: While there might be a million questions and answers about cipher suites out there, there aren't so many that point out the correct reference for customizing them: [The JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-93DEEE16-0B70-40E5-BBE7-55C3FD432345). There's an updated one for each version of Java, that link is for Java 17.

Answer (score 1):

[Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) is a dynamic language. Current version (at time of writing) is 20. When I run your command with Java 20, I get an error:

> script engine for language js can not be found

In fact, the documentation for [jrunscript](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jrunscript.html) states:

> This tool is experimental and unsupported.

However, since it appears to be working in the Java version that you are using (which I could not ascertain from your question), and since it is using [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html), you can add a *filter*. So try the following:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().getSupportedCipherSuites()).stream().filter(s -> "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384".equals(s) || "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384".equals(s)).forEach(println)
```

I suggest that you write a Java [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and use the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html) command. Here is an example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class MyCiphers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> desired = List.of("TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                                       "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
        SSLServerSocketFactory fact = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        String[] supported = fact.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        Arrays.stream(supported)
              .filter(s -> desired.contains(s))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this is only tangenitally related to your question, but depending on what version of java your using, you might not have the full suite of cryptographic algorithms available to you.

Initially, as strong encryption algorithms could not be shipped everywhere due to various legal restrictions, java was shipped with limited crypto algorithms.  To have the full suite of crypto algorithms (including the 'strong' ones), you'll need to apply the official oracle Java Cryptographic Extension patch to both of your java installations.

See https://www.baeldung.com/jce-enable-unlimited-strength for more details.

Comment: While it was a common problem long ago, this issue is now extremely rare. For Oracle builds since 8u161 in 2018, and for all OpenJDK builds since it was created,  'unlimited' policy is the default and no action is needed. And [the Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html) doesn't require providing your personal data to advertisers.